# Editable Angular data grid

Tags: angular

Is there a way to create an excel-like grid using contenteditable span elements in Angular? I understand that a ControlValueAccessor needs to be defined when using contenteditable, but I have a difficult understanding how to update the values in each cell based on user input.

I have this solution built-out already in pure javascript as a web app, and I am trying to convert it to an Angular / Material app. The web app sums up the values (number) entered in each cell, and displays the sum in the last cell of each row.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I have made one material table. In that all first 3 columns are editable and last column is the sum. So if you change first 3 column value it adds up to last column.

Please check below link and let me know if this is what you wanted or not.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kfiqrb?file=src/app/table-basic-example.html

Comment: Thanks for the response, Nirmalya. I am trying to avoid using native input elements. The vanilla web app I am trying to convert was built with custom elements (Web Components).

Comment: I have used div with conetenteditable property in the same example..  please check if its helpful.. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kfiqrb?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-basic-example.html

Comment: Thank you. You answered the question I asked, but I should have rephrased it better.